# China's Paramount Leader

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

> [image]
>
> **Across**
>   1. Non-living bot infiltrates CIA from the back to collect informant's head (7)
>   5. Linux extremist behind pressure associated with revision of ISO standard (5)
>   8. Contained in cardiovascular cells (3)
>   9. Listen, Bill, tin is permanent (5-2)
>   10. Chain of islands, not from East Georgia (5)
>   11. Fighter of Free Siam lost man going around Chinese river (7)
>   13. A yes, in a short way (3)
>   15. Doggone vermins (4)
>   17. Running charge is something that can make one cry (5)
>   19. Soldier trained at Viper (7)
>   21. Sample of grandma's Alsatian sauce (5)
>   23. Sounds unproductive to make a graven image (4)
>   26. During miserable time period (3)
>   27. Rallying a community's leaders within a mile is a marvellous thing (7)
>   29. Loosened ground identified elements (5)
>   30. A devil stands by each charge (7)
>   31. In the style of a Californian city (1, 2)
>   32. Making modification to Dean's car (5)
>   33. A game: Snakes and these Reds, fanatically lead by young man (7)
>
> **Down**
>   1. Shady locale to provide safe place in the absence of hotel (6)
>   2. Coldest cities melted (6)
>   3. To them, no human head is an emblem (5)
>   4. Rover getting into unusually scant oil is arousing debate (13)
>   5. Loyalist at public disturbance stands behind Paramount Leader (7)
>   6. Mentor injured a spine (6)
>   7. Chinese city truly behind Paramount Leader (6)
>   12. Snakes as afterthought (4)
>   14. A plaything's greetings (2-2)
>   16. Greek hero drops axe, cutting left and right; Rhesus's head becomes slightly opened (4)
>   18. Line-dancing man (4)
>   20. Adam ran around for a month (7)
>   21. Osiris's brother raises falsely incriminating efforts (6)
>   22. The Italian dude extraordinarily praised (6)
>   24. Deborah devoured, leading to discussion (6)
>   25. They grant wishes for corporal punishment (6)
>   28. DC returning to host a central property like Superman (5)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The grid:

> ```
>          A B I O T I C   P O S I X
>          R   C   O   O V A   E   I
>          B U I L T I N   T O N G A
>          O   E   E   T   R   P   M
>          U   S A M U R A I   A Y E
>          R A T S     O   O N I O N
>            J   P R I V A T E   Y
>          S A L S A   E     I D O L
>          E R A   M I R A C L E   A
>          T   U   A   S   A   B   S
>          U N D I D   I M P E A C H
>          P   E   A L A   E   T   E
>          S E D A N   L A D D E R S
> ```

Across:

> ```
>  1. Non-living bot infiltrates CIA from the back to     ABIOTIC = B(I)OT in CIA<
>     collect informant's head (7)
>  5. Linux extremist behind pressure associated with     POSIX = P + ISO< + (linu)X
>     revision of ISO standard (5)
>  8. Contained in cardiovascular cells (3)               OVA = cardi_OVA_scular
>  9. Listen, Bill, tin is permanent (5-2)                BUILT-IN = homophone of BILL, TIN
> 10. Chain of islands, not from East Georgia (5)         TONGA = NOT< + GA
> 11. Fighter of Free Siam lost man going around          SAMURAI = AMUR in SIA(m)*
>     Chinese river (7)
> 13. A yes, in a short way (3)                           AYE = ?
> 15. Doggone vermins (4)                                 RATS = double def.
> 17. Running charge is something that can make one       ONION = ON + ION
>     cry (5)
> 19. Soldier trained at Viper (7)                        PRIVATE = (AT VIPER)*
> 21. Sample of grandma's Alsatian sauce (5)              SALSA = grandma_S ALSA_tian
> 23. Sounds unproductive to make a graven image (4)      IDOL = homophone of IDLE
> 26. During miserable time period (3)                    ERA = mis_ERA_ble
> 27. Rallying a community's leaders within a mile is a   MIRACLE = R... A... C... in MILE
>     marvellous thing (7)
> 29. Loosened ground identified elements (5)             UNDID = gro_UND ID_entifed
> 30. A devil stands by each charge (7)                   IMPEACH = IMP + EACH
> 31. In the style of a Californian city (1, 2)           A LA = A + L.A.
> 32. Making modification to Dean's car (5)               SEDAN = DEANS*
> 33. A game: Snakes and these Reds, fanatically lead     (adders and) LADDERS = LAD + REDS*
>     by young man (7)
> ```

Down:

> ```
>  1. Shady locale to provide safe place in the           ARBOUR = (h)ARBOUR
>         absence of hotel (6)
>  2. Coldest cities melted (6)                           ICIEST = CITIES*
>  3. To them, no human head is an emblem (5)             TOTEM = TO + T(h)EM
>  4. Rover getting into unusually scant oil is           CONTROVERSIAL = ROVER in (SCANT OIL)*
>     arousing debate (13)
>  5. Loyalist at public disturbance stands behind        PATRIOT = P... + AT + RIOT
>     Paramount Leader (7)
>  6. Mentor injured a spine (6)                          SENPAI = (A SPINE)*
>  7. Chinese city truly behind Paramount Leader (6)      XIAMEN = XI + AMEN
> 12. Snakes as afterthought (4)                          ASPS = AS + PS (postscript)
> 14. A plaything's greetings (2-2)                       YO-YO = YO! + YO!
> 16. Greek hero drops axe, cutting left and right;       AJAR = AJAX - (a)X(e) + R...
>     Rhesus's head becomes slightly opened (4)
> 18. Line-dancing man (4)                                NEIL = LINE*
> 20. Adam ran around for a month (7)                     RAMADAN = (ADAM RAN)*
> 21. Osiris's brother raises falsely incriminating       SETUPS = SET + UPS
>     efforts (6)
> 22. The Italian dude extraordinarily praised (6)        LAUDED = LA + DUDE*
> 24. Deborah devoured, leading to discussion (6)         DEBATE = DEB + ATE
> 25. They grant wishes for corporal punishment (6)       LASHES = double def.
>                                                         (ref. to wishing on eyelashes)
> 28. DC returning to host a central property like        CAPED = A + (pro)PE(rty) in DC<
>     Superman (5)
> ```